# Given Elo ratings, what is the expected number of points in an X games match?

Tags: probability, expectation

[This guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/2y6ezm/how_to_guide_converting_elo_differences_to/) gives the probability of player $A$ winning a **game** against player $B$, using their Elo ratings $R_A$, $R_B$:

$$P(A) = \frac{1}{1+10^m}$$

where

$$m=\frac{R_B-R_A}{400}$$

What is the expected number of points obtained by player $A$ in an $X$ games match, if a win is worth $1$ point, a draw is worth $0.5$ points and a loss is worth $0$ points?

**Note:** I am not sure if the games should be considered independent or not. One could also factor in the Elo rating changes after one player wins the first game, and the second etc. I'm not sure how much this would complicate computations, so ignoring this is also fine if considering it would be too complex.

Comment: $P(A)X$ and this is explained in the thread you link to. The $P(A)$ is not litterally the probability of winning, but the winning prob, that is the expected [fraction] of points per game. For an actual real match there will of course be other factors like a player that is behind might have to play more agressive in later stages, or  one that is ahead by some marging might go for quick draws rather  than the win but the influence of *that* is obviously not obtainable from the ELO number and mathematical considerations.

Comment: @quid it's not explained in terms of $X$ games, just a single game. The author even highlights this. I am interested in the expected points obtained during an $X$ games match. Of course, there are other non-mathematical considerations, but ignoring those.

Comment: It is mentioned there: "This is for single games, not matches. Carlsen's .61 does not mean he has a 61% chance of winning a match of say 10 games against Anand. **It means that he is expected to get 61% of the points, or 6.1 points.**" The answer is $P(A)X$ as long as the rating is assumed constant. And, but I did not double check this, things are calibrated in such a way that it should stay rather constant. I mean that's the point of it all. The rating predicts the outcome, if you let things play out purely along the lines of what the rating predicts it should not change.

Comment: Ah, that's true. Would it be a lot harder to compute if also taking rating changes between games into consideration?

Comment: @IVlad as a rool ratings calculates after the tournament. Another way leads to a calculating paradoxes

Comment: @quid Such effects are psychological, and mathematician model can not take in account all factors. Rating is a stable statistical parameter.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov sure, that's why I said "but the influence of that is obviously not obtainable from the ELO number and mathematical considerations"

Comment: The point is that I *believe* the expected change will be $0$. The point is the rating difference predicts an outcome. If the actual outcome is better than that predicted by the rating then the rating improves. If it's worse than rating gets worse. But if it is exactly what the rating predicts (and this is what we assume) then it will not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probabilities of the results in each game of $A$ against $B$ are
$$P(W)=\dfrac1{10^m+1}$$
for a win,
$$P(L)=\dfrac1{10^{-m}+1}$$
for a loss,
$$P(D)=1-P(W)-P(L)$$
for a draw,
so expected number of points of $A$ vs $B$ in X games is
$$p=X(P(W)+\dfrac12P(D)),$$
or
$$p(A)=\dfrac{X}2\left(1+\dfrac1{10^{(R_B-R_A)/400}+1}-\dfrac1{10^{(R_A-R_B)/400}+1}\right)$$

Comment: The $P$ in the question is not the probability for a win.